# how do I change the timezone in mysql?

Tags: mysql

how do I change the timezone in mysql? I want to change the timezone to GMT but I don't know how. I want to change the my.cnf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `[mysql]` section of your configuration file and under that section enter this line

```
default-time-zone = '+00:00'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Which `section`?